# Make floated div stick to div it floats around

Tags: css

In this sample, is there any way to align the "sidebar" div to the left so it sticks to "main" div, without setting margin or position manually?

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:1000px;">
<div id="sidebar" style="width:20px; float:right;">Sidebar</div>
<div id="main" style="width:500px; margin:auto;">Main</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make both the main and sidebar div float to one side, and center the whole thing by making wrapper tighter and giving the wrapper auto margins.  The CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 525px;
    margin: auto;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    border: thin solid red;
}
#main {
    width: 500px;
    border: thin solid black;
    float: right;
}
```

You can see the results here, http://jsfiddle.net/BkFgX/